# In Ruby or Rails, hash.merge({:order => 'asc'}) can return a new hash with a new key. What can return a new hash with a deleted key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Ruby (or Rails), we can do

```
new_params = params.merge({:order => 'asc'})
```

and now `new_params` is a hash with an added key `:order`.

But is there a line there can return the hash with a deleted key?  The line

```
new_params = params.delete(:order)
```

won't work because the `delete` method returns the value and that's it.  Do we have to do it in 3 steps?

```
tmp_params = params
tmp_params.delete(:order)
return tmp_params
```

Is there a better way?  Because I want to do a

```
new_params = (params[:order].blank? || params[:order] == 'desc') ? 
               params.merge({:order => 'asc') : 
               (foo = params; foo.delete(:order); foo)   # return foo
```

but the last line above is somewhat clumsy.  Is there a better way to do it?

(note: because the default order is 'desc', so when there is no `order` param, that means it is the default and is `desc`, then toggle it to add `order=asc`, but otherwise, just remove the param `order` so that it is back to the default order of `desc`)

Comment: Do you want to change (destruct) `params`? If you do, you should do it directly as `tmp_params.delete(:order)`. If not, you need to `dup` before `delete`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`ActiveSupport` adds a `Hash#except` method:

```
h1 = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
h1.except(:a) #=> {:b=>2, :c=>3}
```

A more complicated example:

```
h1 = { a:1, b: 2, c: 3 }
h2 = { b: 3, d: 5 }
h1.merge(h2).except(*h1.keys-h2.keys) #=> {:b=>3, :d=>5}
```

This will update keys that are present in `h1` with the ones in `h2`, add the new ones from `h2` and remove the ones that are in `h1` but not in `h2`.

Answer (score 1):

use reject:

```
{:hello=> 'aaa'}.reject {| key, value | key == :hello} #=> {}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to depend on ActiveSupport you can use:

```
params.delete_if {|key, value| key == :order }
```

Comment: to summarize, the `except` and `reject` method doesn't change the original hash, while `delete_if` actually changes the original hash